# Django Saving A Model With Form + Current User Data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm writing my first app in django and i have encountered a problem. I'm trying to make a booking system. I'm trying to save the reservation model. It works just fine while the user is logged out. But once i click submit while logged in nothing really happens. The site simply reloads. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?
That's my model code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 9)

class Reservation(models.Model):
    reservationID = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 9)
    email = models.EmailField()
    bookIn = models.DateField('Book in date', default = timezone.now)
    bookOut = models.DateField('Book out date', default = timezone.now)
    roomType = models.ForeignKey(Room_type, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

My form:

```
class Booking(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = ('name', 'surname', 'phone', 'email', 'roomType', 'bookIn', 'bookOut',)
    widgets = {
        'bookIn': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
        'bookOut': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'})
        }
```

And my view:

```
form = Booking()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Booking(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            reservation = Reservation()
            guest = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            reservation.name = guest.name
            reservation.surname = guest.surname
            reservation.phone = guest.phone
            reservation.email = guest.user.email
            reservation.bookIn = form.cleaned_data.get('bookIn')
            reservation.bookOut = form.cleaned_data.get('bookOut')
            reservation.roomType = form.cleaned_data.get('roomType')
            reservation.save()

        else:
            reservation = form.save()
            reservation.save()

        n = reservation.pk
        return redirect('bookSuccess', n)
return render(request, 'hotel/bookRoom.html', {'form' : form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your form is not validating for some reason, and you need to catch it to see what might be going wrong. So you can update your view like this:

```
form = Booking(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            # optimized the code
            guest = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            reservation.name = guest.name
            reservation.surname = guest.surname
            reservation.phone = guest.phone
            reservation.email = request.user.email
            reservation.save()
        else:
            reservation = form.save()  # removed duplicate save

        n = reservation.pk
        return redirect('bookSuccess', n)
return render(request, 'hotel/bookRoom.html', {'form' : form})
```

#### Update

You don't need to put **null** **true** and **blank** **true** in the model fields. You can pass the `user` data from view to form. and if the user is authenticated then pop the fields which is not necessary for authenticated user. Like this:

```
class Booking(forms.ModelForm):

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           user = kwargs.pop('user')
           super(Booking, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           if user.is_authenticated:
               self.fields.pop('name')  # or make them required false like this:  self.fields['name'].required = False
               self.fields.pop('surname')
               # other fields unnecessary for authenticated user
      # rest of the code
```

And use this form in view like this:

```
form = Booking(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
```

Comment: It didn't validate, because the fields name, surname etc. were required. I can overcome this by just adding "blank=true" in model, but it would cause a problem for anonymous users which could book rooms without these fields. Is there a way to make it required for anonymous users and not required for logged users?

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it tomorrow!